# LNK2019 unresolved external symbol using GLFW

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opengl, glfw, lnk2019

Probably the most asked question on GLFW ever. But I've tried everything I can think of and after 3 hours of googling I give up.

What I've been able to understand is that this error occours when:

> The compiled code for function makes a reference or call to symbol, but that symbol isn't defined in any of the libraries or object files specified to the linker.

That means I must have simply failed linking the library as I understand.

Ok so located in: "C:\dev\MyVSProjects\MyWorld\dependencies\OpenGL\GLFW\lib-vc2015"
is my glfw3.lib file.

Inside of my solutions Property Pages I set "Additional Library Directories" to "$(SolutionDir)dependencies\OpenGL\GLFW\lib-vc2015" which is where the above file is located relavtive to the .sln file.

Then finally in the linker I set Additional Dependencies to: "opengl32.lib;glfw3.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)"

Thats pretty simple, and I just dont understand how that cannot be linked correctly.

Im using glad in my project btw and it works correctly, also both the glfw3.h and glad.h files are found. (And yes im including glad.h first).

Yet every GLFW function gets the unresolved external symbol error.

So my question is why am i still getting these unresolved external symbol linking errors.

Answer (score -1):

Alright so it turns out I did do everything correctly. The 64-bit binaries simply does not work with Visual studio 17...

If your experienceing the same issue simply get the 32 bit binaries.

Comment: They do work. You just need to download the source code and build them for the 64-bit platform.

Comment: Yes Nadir as i said the prebuild binaries do not work. Atleast it didnt for me and for lots of other people..

Comment: How do you build the binaries? You need first to build the Visual studio files using cmake. When running cmake, you have to choose wether to build them for x86 or x64. If you choose x64, you can the open GLFW solution and targer x64 prior to build it. I build them from time to time to update my binaries with the lastest updates, never had a problem